# Error when installing sas7bdat package into Rstudio running on Linux Redhat server

Tags: linux, r, github, sas, redhat

I keep getting errors when trying to read a sas7bdat file in R studio. My R studio is running on a Linux Redhat Server. I've tried to install the different versions of the sas7bdat package.

- Installed the 0.1 version

> install.packages("~/sas7bdat_0.1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type
>   ="source")
>
> library(sas7bdat)
>
> read.sas7bdat({file})

*unknown host 9.0301M2 please report bugs to sas7bdatRbugs@gmail.com*

- Installed the 0.2 version (http://biostatmatt.com/archives/1712)

> install.packages("~/sas7bdat_0.2.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type =
>   "source")
>
> ```
> library(sas7bdat)
>
> read.sas7bdat({file})
> ```

*Error in read.sas7bdat("/home/raffie/all.sas7bdat") : 
    unknown host 01M2Linu please report bugs to sas7bdatRbugs@gmail.com*

- Installed the 0.3 version (from cran)

> install.packages("~/sas7bdat_0.3.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type =
>   "source")
>
> library(sas7bdat)
>
> read.sas7bdat({file})

*found 0 row size subheaders where 1 expected please report bugs to 
   sas7bdatRbugs@gmail.com*

---

The same errors appear when I called the commands in RStudio running in Windows, with the respective versions of the package installed. However, when I installed the package using the install_github("sas7bdat","BioStatMatt) command, I was then able to read sas7bdat files. But the same cannot be said when I tried to install the package using the install_github command on the Linux server RStudio. The error was:

```
> install_github("sas7bdat","BioStatMatt")
```

- checking for file '/tmp/Rtmpu0f5Xu/devtools3ce32ba1e1fd/sas7bdat-master/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
- preparing 'sas7bdat':
- checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
- installing the package to build vignettes
- creating vignettes ... ERROR Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  :    Running 'texi2dvi' on 'sas7bdat.tex' failed. LaTeX errors: ! LaTeX Error: File `ltcaption.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or  to proceed, or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
! Emergency stop.  
          l.9 \setlength
              {\extrarowheight}{2pt}^^M !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced! Calls:  -> texi2pdf -> texi2dvi Execution halted

Error: Command failed (1)

---

I think the version on Github is the only version that can work for me currently (the sas7bdat-master version). This is because it works when I use it in Windows.

Link: https://github.com/BioStatMatt/sas7bdat

However, only the .zip file is available. I tried to convert it to a .tar.gz file, and then install the package (the RStudio on Linux server can only install .tar.gz packages). The following error was found:

Error in untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir, restore_times) : unsupported entry type ‘’

---

What can I do about this? Are the errors I'm getting mainly because my RStudio running on a Linux Redhat server (x86_64) can only read .tar.gz packages? The command read.sas7bdat works in the RStudio running in my windows 7 PC, when I used install_github command.

Comment: Have you taken the advice suggested by the original error message?

Comment: yes I've emailed sas7bdatRbugs@gmail.com. Waiting for reply.

Comment: update: I still have not got any reply from sas7bdatRbugs@gmail.com. I suspect this problem is because of incompatibility of the sas7bdat package with linux redhat

Comment: Why not raise an issue on the github page (the package author is maintaining it)

Comment: Will do and will follow up on the answer. Right now there's no concrete answer from the author. Recent results indicate that sas7bdat files created in windows can be read in both windows and linux. However, sas7bdat files created in linux can be read in windows but not in linux.